# MySQL IPv4 Validation implementation

Tags: mysql, ipv4

Hello guys it is my first post

I am struggling here for the past two days in implementing validation for ipv4 address....
The problem is that the validation should be performed on database level and this makes it difficult for noob like me

So I have to make :

1. Validation of ipv4 address
2. If the prefix somewhere in the ip is 0 I have to remove it (example : 123.013.221.011 
   should become 123.13.221.11)

What I have so far in a trigger:

This is not working as it is supposed to, so I am asking you guys for help...thanks !!!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER validation_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON setting_parameters
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
-- PROXY RULES --
   IF(NEW.parameter_name LIKE '%proxy%') = true THEN 
     IF(INET_ATON(NEW.parameter_value)<INET_ATON('255.255.255.255'))=true THEN 
        IF(NEW.parameter_name LIKE '0%') = true THEN 
           SET NEW.parameter_value = SUBSTR(NEW.parameter_value,2);
        ELSE 
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Wrong PROXY parameter values !';
        END IF;
     END IF;
   END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. Consider implementing this functionality as a [User Defined Functions (or UDF)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html). This will allow you to write code in either `c` or `c++` rather than `SQL`.

Alternatively, You can use [REGEXP support in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html).

This is a solution for Part 1 of your question:

This example is for validating an `IPV4` address using `REGEXP`

```
SELECT '123.1.2.3'
REGEXP '^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[013-9][0-9]|12[0-689]|2[0-4][1-9]|25[0-4])\.(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){2}([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][1-9]|25[0-4])$'
;
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/244cd/1/0)

(**Note:** I have never used triggers myself. Hence cannot give you ready-to-use code. But you can use this example to make a trigger out of it)

I think solution for part 2 is a simple find-and-replace. Here again a REGEXP can be used to match all the patterns of `0`, `00`, `.0`, `.00` and replace with a `.` (or nothing, if beginning of string)

**Update 2:**

Here is an SQL example to remove leading zeros. I did not have to use REGEXP here since `CAST()` did the magic!

```
SELECT ip, 
    CONCAT_WS('.',CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',1) as UNSIGNED), 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',2),'.',-1) as UNSIGNED), 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',-2),'.',1) as UNSIGNED), 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',-1) as UNSIGNED))  as Converted_IP
FROM ip_addr;
```

If `ip_addr` is a table with a column named `ip` and values like this

```
-------------    
IP
-------------
127.0.0.1
001.02.0.123
1.23.123.000
-------------
```

The `SQL` will Output:

```
-----------------------------
IP              CONVERTED_IP
-----------------------------
127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1
001.02.0.123    1.2.0.123
1.23.123.000    1.23.123.0
-----------------------------
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10ab6/5/0)

**Update 3:**

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963203/1243123)  solution by [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) is awesome

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a shot and write back!!

Comment: Hey the regexp for ipv4 worked great...unfortunatelly I can not make the find-replace regex for 00,.0, and .00 could you provide an example on how to do that ? thanks big time !!

Comment: Updated my answer with an SQL example for Part 2. have a look.

Answer (score 2):

There are pre-implemented functions to check the validity of an ip address.
please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

Simply call IS_IPV4()