# Mysql Regex to replace 0 from ipv4

Tags: mysql, regex

I cannot make a mysql regexp which would remove zeros in the beggining of each 3 number sequences of IPv4.
The problem is that the validation should be provided on database level and I don't know how to formulate the regex which would replace all 0., 00., .0, .00 with emtpy string from my IPv4.

I want my regex to do something like that :

If I have 012.123.123.023 entering the database it should be saved as 12.123.123.23

Thank you !

Comment: MySQL does not support regex replacement natively. Are you planning to do this in a trigger? It can be done with a complex string of `REPLACE()` calls.

Comment: What do you mean by the "validation should be provided on database level"? It doesn't seem you are talking about validation at all (i.e. verifying the number ranges are correct), but rather string manipulation. Are you pulling data from the database and you need to replace zeroes before viewing?  Are you inserting data into the database and need to remove zeroes before doing so? Your use case is not clear, and it is very likely that you should be doing this at the application level, likely without even requiring the use of a regex, but rather a simple string replacement.

Comment: This sort of thing is super easy with any scripting language with a functional regular expression substitution method, but super obnoxious in pure MySQL.

Comment: I need to insert ipv4 in the database but not from an application level. In my trigger I have to make sure that it does not have zeros in wrong places. Isn't this kind of a validation Mike ? And no I dont have to do this on application level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By utilizing the MySQL functions [`INET_ATON()` and `INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) you can reliably convert an incoming IPv4 address which has leading zeros into the same string without leading zeros.  Wrap `INET_ATON()` with `INET_NTOA()` to convert the IP address first to its integer value, and then back to a dotted quad.

#### IP with leading zeros in various places:

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('001.110.011.111'));
+-----------------------------------------+
| INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('001.110.011.111')) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 1.110.11.111                            |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

#### And without leading zeros for comparison:

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('1.110.11.111'));
+--------------------------------------+
| INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('1.110.11.111')) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 1.110.11.111                         |
+--------------------------------------+
```

**Note:** This will return `NULL` if the input IP address was not a valid address. It won't return the original string or strip leading zeros from a bad IP address:

#### Faulty IP address with leading zeros:

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('888.777.123.123'));
+-----------------------------------------+
| INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('888.007.123.123')) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: +1 for this trick! Awesome. [My Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19959884/1243123) was less awesome